# (joomla) responsiv menu button changes not class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

somebody has an idea why this button in the 
"(nav class="sidebar-collapse")" 
not worth the "toggled" on there?

So in the end it looks like 
"(nav class="sidebar-collapse toggled")".

EDIT: to the left is a vertical menu, and above from the menu is a button when you click the button the menu will fold in and out.

**Button**

```
<button type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="toggler"></button>
```

**Sidebar:**

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-collapse">
<div class="side-widgets overflow">
    <!-- Profile Menu -->
    <div class="text-center s-widget m-b-25 dropdown" id="profile-menu">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml" />
    </div>
    <div class="s-widget m-b-25">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="xhtml" />
    </div>
    <!-- User 2 -->
    <div class="s-widget m-b-25">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" style="xhtml" />
    </div>
    <!-- User 3 -->
    <div class="s-widget m-b-25">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" style="xhtml"/>
    </div>
</div>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" />
```

just want to know why the code does not work yet.

when I click the button, the class of a div to change.

and jquery does not work

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".toggler").click(function(){

            $(".sidebar-collapse").toggleClass("toggled");

        });

    });
```

Comment: is it bootstrap accordion? And can you please make the question more  clear?

Comment: its bootstrap. 
just want to know why the code does not work yet.

when I click the button, the class of a div to change.

and jqury does not work

Comment: Beacause it doesn't work like that. If you provide all your css and html I can do some js for you so that it will work as expected. Alternatively you can use bootstrap navbar http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar. Which is quite handy. It's hard to tell from these jdocs what this menu looks like

Comment: here you can test it http://nova-arts.net , in the top left korner is the button and left the menu, webseite not finished jet, at 12:00 p.m. website goes in service mode